# Mount hard drive to new CentOS 6 install

Tags: linux, mount, lvm

I installed Linux CentOS 6 on a new hard drive. GNOME automatically mounted my old drive to `/media/bf90bc42-1b10-4c6f-9b58-f0e52d103907`.
Long number maybe is a some type of UUID. I even umounted it with same results.

I want to mount `vg_wiwan50-lv_root` to `/mnt/WD2TB` and my other hard drives (data stuff, not system boot stuff).

These LVM confuse me so much (computer nerd for 20 years with servers).

I tried these commands:

```
[root@server /]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part
└─sda2   8:2    0   1.8T  0 part
  ├─vg_wiwan50-lv_root (dm-3)
       253:3    0   1.7T  0 lvm  /media/bf90bc42-1b10-4c6f-9b58-f0e52d103907
  ├─vg_wiwan50-lv_home (dm-4)
       253:4    0 109.6G  0 lvm
  └─vg_wiwan50-lv_swap (dm-5)
       253:5    0     3G  0 lvm
sdb      8:16   0 149.1G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0   149G  0 part /media/disk3
sdc      8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk
sdd      8:48   0 223.6G  0 disk
├─sdd1   8:49   0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sdd2   8:50   0 223.1G  0 part
  ├─vg_wiwan45-lv_root (dm-0)
       253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg_wiwan45-lv_swap (dm-1)
       253:1    0   7.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─vg_wiwan45-lv_home (dm-2)
       253:2    0 165.4G  0 lvm  /home



[root@server WD2TB]# mount -t lvm2 /dev/sda2 /mnt/WD2TB
mount: unknown filesystem type 'lvm2'
[root@server WD2TB]# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/WD2TB
mount: /dev/sda2 already mounted or /mnt/WD2TB busy
[root@server WD2TB]# umount /dev/sda2
umount: /dev/sda2: not mounted
[root@server WD2TB]# umount -l  /media/bf90bc42-1b10-4c6f-9b58-f0e52d103907
[root@server WD2TB]# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/WD2TB
mount: /dev/sda2 already mounted or /mnt/WD2TB busy
[root@server WD2TB]# umount -l /media/bf90bc42-1b10-4c6f-9b58-f0e52d103907
umount: /media/bf90bc42-1b10-4c6f-9b58-f0e52d103907: not found
[root@server WD2TB]# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/WD2TB
mount: /dev/sda2 already mounted or /mnt/WD2TB busy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some basic information about LVM can be found [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html-single/logical_volume_manager_administration/index#LVM_components), you are trying to mount `/dev/sda2` which is a physical volume and can't be mounted, you need to mount the logical volume(s):

`mount /dev/mapper/vg_wiwan50-lv_root /mnt/<mountpoint>`

for root filesystem and

`mount /dev/mapper/vg_wiwan50-lv_home /mnt/<mountpoint>`

for home filesystem.

The automount to `/media/bf90bc42-1b10-4c6f-9b58-f0e52d103907` is done by UDisks, if you want these logical volumes mounted automatically to `/mnt` or other "custom" mountpoint, use [fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab).

Comment: thanks how would i add mount /dev/mapper/vg_wiwan50-lv_root /mnt/<mountpoint>

 to fstab ?

Comment: would "/dev/mapper/vg_wiwan50-lv_root /mnt/WD2TB                       ext4    defaults        1 1" work ?

Comment: Yes, that looks good.